# error Key sequence starts with non-prefix key

Tags: key-bindings

After trying to define a custom binding:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "g l") 'evil-end-of-line)
```

I get:

`(error Key sequence g h starts with non-prefix key g)`

because `g` is the start of navigation for many commands in evil.

How can I make it use my binding (which isn't bound to any other command: `g l`) whilst keeping evil's prefix binding?

Since `g` is the prefix for other evil commands, I'm unable to use it with another combo. I still want to keep other `g <key>` commands like `g g`

Comment: Please clarify: You want `g` to both (1) perform navigation as soon as you hit it and (2) wait for you to hit `l` and then invoke `evil-end-of-line` instead? You could perhaps use `sit-for` and after that delay (i.e., if no user input) then use the usual `g` command, else, if `l` is hit within that delay use your eol command.

Comment: @Drew `g` is the start of navigation for many commands in `evil`. So I want to use the combination that isn't bound to any other command: `g l`. But because `g` is the prefix for other evil commands, I'm unable to use it with another combo. I still want to keep other `g ...` commands like `gg` without a delay.

Comment: Please put such clarifying info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're manipulating the wrong map:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "g l") 'evil-end-of-line))
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for completeness, this is it set in Doom Emacs: `(map! :n "g l" 'evil-end-of-line)`