# Keybindings without a prefix key?

Tags: key-bindings

In my emacs, `tide-mode` has a key for `jump-to-definition` of `g d`

I would like to define keys like this where i do not need a prefix (I use evil, so it would be in normal mode).

When I try this:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "g c c") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

I get the message: `Key sequence g c c starts with a non-prefix key`

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The message is telling you that `g` or `g c` is not a prefix key. See `define-prefix-command`. See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13418 and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/58264.

Comment: You can define the key combo in evil-motion-state-map: `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "gcc") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)`.

Comment: Yes that worked for me. I am curious why the evil map allows keybindings without a prefix, while the global key map does not.

Comment: The global map *does* allow that (or rather, there's nothing preventing that in general for *any* keymap).  But `g` is *already* bound to a command in the global map, therefore (as the error tells you) it cannot also be a prefix.

Comment: The take away is that if you want to change `evil` key bindings, you should use `evil` keymaps.